# Android manifest android:installLocation only work in 2.2?

Tags: android

Android manifest android:installLocation only work in 2.2?
Not in 2.1? :( Is there a way to check the android version? If android version is 2.2 then use the `installLocation auto`? Not in XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's available only from API level 8 (that is Android 2.2), see [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html).
You can retrieve the version number from [`android.os.Build.VERSION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html)